# change background color of Div with style in tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a Div change its background color on hover but it's not working.

----------HTML-----------

```
   <div class="home-circles" style="background-color:#92cd00">
        <span style="color:#1C263C"><b>About Me</b></span>
        </div>

   <div class="home-circles" style="background-color:#FFCF79">
    <span style="color:#663333"><b>Music</b></span>
    </div>

    <div class="home-circles" style="background-color:#E5E4D7">
    <span style="color:#097054"><b>Hi Morgane</b></span>
    </div>
```

----------CSS------------

```
.home-circles {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border-radius: 200px; 
    margin:25px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:250px;
    font-size:50px;
    font-family:rochester;

    -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 12px; 
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.home-circles:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

The problem seems to be the style attribute in the div. The background color specified in the Div seem to supersede the one specified in .home-circles:hover. Is there a way to get around it without changing the CSS for .home-circles?

Comment: if you don' t have access to html, try with !important....

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using inline style for all your divs with class `home-circles` such as `background-color:#FFCF79`, `background-color:#E5E4D7`.... in your HTML which will override the style you've defined in your external CSS `background-color:#fff`.

You can use `!important` property here:

```
.home-circles:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Mx29/)**

> When an !important rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever
>   it is in the declaration list. Although, !important has nothing to do
>   with specificity.  Using !important is bad practice because it makes
>   debugging hard since you break the natural cascading in your
>   stylesheets

So basically, you can use `!important` but it's discouraged. I'd suggest you to move your inline styles to external CSS files instead.

Answer (score 1):

just use !important in hover css

```
.home-circles:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/66qng/)

Note:inline styles must be overrided,since you are giving background-color in `style` u should use `!important` to override it.

[**When Using !important is The Right Choice**](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

> Using !important in your CSS usually means you're narcissistic &
>   selfish or lazy. Respect the devs to come...

Answer (score 0):

You have a small mistake.

First of all you have to know hierarchy of css. In your div tag inline css background which is 
first priority that's why your hover action not working. your default background color should come from css class then hover color will work properly

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, that completely escaped my mind!

Answer (score 0):

Use the !important property! This will override the inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .mydiv
            {
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                background-color:red;
            }
            .mydiv:hover
            {
                background-color:blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mydiv">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```